# Getting data from an oledb database to a datagrid view in VB.Net

Tags: sql, vb.net

Trying to pull data from a database and show it in a table on a data grid view.
The table with the heading is being created but it wont populate with the values.
Some of the code is commented out as im trying to work 2 tables first.
Would appreciate any helping hand, basic knowledge of visual basic!

Public Class DriverOption

```
Public Sub btnStaff_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStaff.Click

    Dim objconnection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=msdaora;Data Source=orabis;User Id=112221800;Password=112221800;")

    Dim objinvoicesDA As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from CUSORDER, CUSORDER ", objconnection)

    Dim objinvoicesCB As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(objinvoicesDA)

    Dim objdataset As New DataSet()


    Dim objordersdA As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select CUSORDER.ORDERID, CUSORDER.ORDERDATE, CUSORDER.STAFFID, CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID,  CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERADD_1 FROM CUSORDER,CUSTOMER WHERE CUSORDER.CUSTOMERID = CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID", objconnection)  'orderdetails.unitprice from orders , orderdetails where orders.orderid = orderdetails.orderid", objconnection)

    Dim objordersCB As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(objordersdA)

    'Dim objcustomersDA As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from CUSTOMER", objconnection)

    'Dim objcustomersCB As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(objcustomersDA)


    'Dim objproductsDA As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from Products", objconnection)

    'Dim objproductsCB As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(objproductsDA)


    'Public Sub retrieve()
    'objdataset.Clear()

    'objproductsDA.FillSchema(objdataset, SchemaType.Source, "Products")


    'objproductsDA.Fill(objdataset, "Products")


    'objcustomersDA.FillSchema(objdataset, SchemaType.Source, "CUSTOMER")


    'objcustomersDA.Fill(objdataset, "CUSTOMER")
    objordersdA.FillSchema(objdataset, SchemaType.Source, "CUSTOMER")


    objordersdA.Fill(objdataset, "CUSTOMER")

    objordersdA.FillSchema(objdataset, SchemaType.Source, "CUSORDER")


    objordersdA.Fill(objdataset, "CUSORDER")


    'objinvoicesDA.FillSchema(objdataset, SchemaType.Source, "invoices")


    'objinvoicesDA.Fill(objdataset, "invoices")


    ViewDeliverys.DataGridView1.DataSource = objdataset.Tables("CUSORDER")
```

Answer (score 0):

got any error ?
have you tried to debug the code and see if you populate the dataset and  where is the problem? 
 I don't understand this query  Dim objinvoicesDA ...("select * from CUSORDER, CUSORDER ", objconnection) : this "CUSORDER, CUSORDER " this type of query exists?